# How to remove borders of the window created by GLUT?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, glut, border

The question is quite clear, GLUT provides us functions to create a windowed application. But presently I need to re-design the title bar, and also the border styles. Anyway to remove the **borders** and **title bar**? (certainly I'm talking about C++ or Visual C++ 'cause this is an OpenGL related question)

Comment: Why would this being an OpenGL related question imply that you are talking about C++?  OpenGL is written in C, and there are [bindings for it in a wide variety of languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL#Bindings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least three options:

1. Modify your GLUT implementation to add this feature.  If you're using FreeGLUT look into the implementation of `fgOpenWindow()` in `freeglut_window.c`.
2. Use a different framework that supports this feature.  It looks like [SFML should](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/namespacesf_1_1Style.php).
3. Manage the OS interface yourself.

Answer (score 5):

GLUT is a simplicistic framework without much functionality. What you want to do is simply not featured by GLUT and can't be done with it. Practically this means, you have to roll your own thing, which, luckily, is not so hard. Or you use one of the two open source variants of GLUT (FreeGLUT and OpenGLUT) and extend them with your desires.